# GoogleMaps JS API crashes to white/grey screen after random amount of time

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, webview, javafx

I am making a JavaFX application which contains a Web View. The web view loads a HTML/JavaScript page showing Google Maps using their JS API.

My JavaFX app listens to another library which returns statistics such as Latitude/Longitude data, which I then plot on Google Maps at regular intervals (every second or so). These are plotted by drawing a polyline from the previous plot to the new one, and/or creating another marker. This is done by calling `webView.getEngine().executeScript("...some script, plus params...");`.

This works absolutely fine for anything between 20 minutes - 1.5hrs, but seemingly randomly, Google Maps will suddenly render no map at all, instead just a *slightly off **white*** colour. After this point Google Maps will not 'recover'.

**This is how the window looks**

*Working*

[image: Working]

*Having Crashed*

[image: Having 'crashed']

**The Java code which is executed once every second is:**

```
public void moveMapImage(float lati, float longi)
{


    final float finalLati = lati;
    final float finalLongi = longi;

    if(webView.getEngine().getLoadWorker().getState().equals(Worker.State.SUCCEEDED))
    {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run()
            {
                if(!viewingRoute){webView.getEngine().executeScript("moveTo("+finalLati+", "+finalLongi+")");}//Only move camera if not viewing route
                else{webView.getEngine().executeScript("addToPolyLine("+finalLati+", "+finalLongi+")");}
            }
         });
    }
}
```

**The JS code which is called by the code above once every second is:**

```
      function moveTo(lati, longi)
      {
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lati, longi, true); 
        map.panTo(latLng);
        addToPolyLine(lati, longi);
      }

      function addToPolyLine(lati,longi)
      { 
        var newLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lati, longi);
        previousLatLong = newLatLng;
        path.getPath().push(newLatLng);     

        if(allMarkers.length <= 0) //Add start marker
        {
            placeStartStopMarker(lati, longi);
        }

        if(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(previousMarker, newLatLng) >= mileSymbolDistance) //Add Interval Markers
        {
            previousMarker = newLatLng;
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: newLatLng,
                map: map,
                icon: diamondSymbolDistMarker,
                title: 'Distance Marker'
              });

              allMarkers.push(marker);
        }

      }
```

There is no error returned in the Java console at all.

What might I be doing wrong?
Is it possible I'm panning the map to a new location too many times?

#### EDIT: My Entire Google Maps JS Code:

```
var map;
var mapTypeToUse = google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE;
var pathCoords = [];
var path;
var zoomLevel = 15;
var mileSymbolDistance = 10;
var previousLatLong;

var mapOptions;
var previousMarker = new google.maps.LatLng(50.7682405,0.2971879);
var curMarker;
var lineColourToUse = '#FF0000';
var allMarkers = [];
var invisibleMarker = {path: 'M -1,0 0,-1 1,0 0,1 z',strokeColor: '#F00',fillColor: '#F00',fillOpacity: 0};
var diamondSymbolDistMarker = {path: 'M -6,0 0,-6 6,0 0,6 z',strokeColor: '#F00',fillColor: '#F00',fillOpacity: 1};
var diamondSymbolStopMarker = {path: 'M -10,5 10,5 10,-5 -10,-5 z',strokeColor: '#F00',fillColor: '#F00',fillOpacity: 1};
var diamondSymbolStart = {path: 'M -10,0 0,-10 10,0 0,10 z',strokeColor: '#0CF27D',fillColor: '#0CF27D',fillOpacity: 0.8};


    function initialize() {
        initializeNewMap();

        path = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: pathCoords,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: lineColourToUse,
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2
        });
        path.setMap(map);

        //previousMarker = (new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0));
    }

    function initializeNewMap()
    {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: previousMarker,
          zoom: zoomLevel,
          mapTypeId: mapTypeToUse,
          draggable: false,
          disableDefaultUI: true,
          zoomControl: false
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            mapOptions);
    }

      function eastbourne()
      {
          var mapOptions = {center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.7682405,0.2971879),zoom: zoomLevel,mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE 
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                mapOptions);
      }

      function moveTo(lati, longi)
      {
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lati, longi, true); 
        map.panTo(latLng);
        addToPolyLine(lati, longi);
      }

      function clearPolyLines()
      {
            path.setMap(null);
            path = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: pathCoords,
            geodesic: true,
            strokeColor: lineColourToUse,
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 2

            });
            path.setMap(map);


            previousMarker = (new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0));
            clearMarkers();
      }

      function clearMarkers()
      {
        for (var i = 0; i < allMarkers.length; i++) {
        allMarkers[i].setMap(null);
        }
        allMarkers = [];
      }

      function addToPolyLine(lati,longi)
      { 
        var newLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lati, longi);
        previousLatLong = newLatLng;
        path.getPath().push(newLatLng);
        //previousMarker = new google.maps.LatLng(lati, longi);
        //console.log(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(previousMarker, newLatLng));

        if(allMarkers.length <= 0) //Add start marker
        {
            placeStartStopMarker(lati, longi);
        }

        if(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(previousMarker, newLatLng) >= mileSymbolDistance) //Add Interval Markers
        {
            previousMarker = newLatLng;
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: newLatLng,
                map: map,
                icon: diamondSymbolDistMarker,
                title: 'Distance Marker'
              });

              allMarkers.push(marker);
        }

      }

      function addStationStopMarker(lati, longi)
      {
            if(path.getPath().getLength() > 4)
            {
                var markerLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lati, longi);
                //var angleValue = (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(path.getPath().getAt(path.getPath().getLength()-2,path.getPath().getAt(path.getPath().getLength()-3))) + (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(path.getPath().getAt(path.getPath().getLength()-1,path.getPath().getAt(path.getPath().getLength()-2))) + (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(markerLatLng,path.getPath().getAt(path.getPath().getLength()-1))) / 3; //Gets the mean of the last three points - hopefully this will be more accurate!
                var angleValue = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(markerLatLng,path.getPath().getAt(path.getPath().getLength()-1));
                var rotatedStopMarker = {path: 'M -10,5 10,5 10,-5 -10,-5 z',strokeColor: lineColourToUse,fillColor: lineColourToUse,fillOpacity: 1, rotation: angleValue};
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: markerLatLng,
                        map: map,
                        icon: rotatedStopMarker,
                        title: 'Stop Marker'
                      });

                      allMarkers.push(marker);
                }

      }

      function zoomIn(amount)
      {
            zoomLevel+=amount;
            if(zoomLevel <= 1){zoomLevel = 1;}
            else if(zoomLevel > 20){zoomLevel = 20;}
            map.setZoom(zoomLevel);
      }

      function setZoomLevel(amount)
      {
        zoomLevel=amount;
        //map.setZoom(zoomLevel);
      }

    function setMileSymbolDistance(value)
    {
        mileSymbolDistance = value;
    }

    function setMapType(id)
    {
        if(id == 1){mapTypeToUse = google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP;}
        else if(id == 2){mapTypeToUse = google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID ;}
        else if(id == 3){mapTypeToUse = google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN ;}
        else{mapTypeToUse = google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE;}
        initializeNewMap();
        path.setMap(map);
        for (var i = 0; i < allMarkers.length; i++) {
        allMarkers[i].setMap(map);
        }
    }

    function zoomToFitRoute()
    {
        //if(allMarkers.length >= 2){
            addInvisMarkerAt(previousLatLong);
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            for(i=0;i<allMarkers.length;i++) {
             bounds.extend(allMarkers[i].getPosition());
            }

            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        //}

    }

    function addInvisMarkerAt(latlong)
    {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlong,
            map: map,
            icon: invisibleMarker,
            title: 'Invisible Marker'
          });

          allMarkers.push(marker);
    }

    function placeStartStopMarker(lati, longi)
    {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position:  new google.maps.LatLng(lati, longi),
                    map: map,
                    icon: diamondSymbolStart,
                    title: 'Start/Stop Marker'
                  });

                  allMarkers.push(marker);
    }

    function finishRoute(lati, longi)
    {
        placeStartStopMarker(lati, longi)
        zoomToFitRoute();
    }

    function setLineColour(newColour)
    {
        lineColourToUse = "#"+newColour;
        diamondSymbolDistMarker = {path: 'M -6,0 0,-6 6,0 0,6 z',strokeColor: lineColourToUse,fillColor: lineColourToUse,fillOpacity: 1};
        diamondSymbolStopMarker = {path: 'M -10,5 10,5 10,-5 -10,-5 z',strokeColor: lineColourToUse,fillColor: lineColourToUse,fillOpacity: 1};
        clearPolyLines();
    }
```

Comment: I would guess that the function `moveMapImage` will be called with invalid values for `lati` or `longi`. check these values....`lati` may be between -85 and 85 and `longi` between -180 and 180

Comment: I have just amended my code to ensure that no erroneous values get past- which they aren't. Still the problem persists. I notice that after a certain point, Google Maps will just stop **drawing** the map itself, as if it's using too much memory. How can I ensure Google Maps only keeps what is visible, in memory?

Comment: I made it test, it's running now for 2 hours and 8000 markers on a polyline have been drawn....the map is still OK. I will keep it running all night long to see what happens.

Comment: after 8 hours and 32000 markers the map was still there, the memory-consumption  didn't grow(Firefox).

Comment: I've attached all of my Java Script code. Would you mind telling me if you find anything which is incorrect? Just to reiterate; the JS code is executed from within JavaFX's web-view. Would the JavaFX web view limit the amount of memory usage?

Comment: If anyone is able to help, I am still completely stuck with this issue.